# Es posible lograr la configuración de Laragon implementando Virtual Host y la ejecución de múltiples versiones de php al mismo tiempo?

Tags: php, virtualhost, laragon

Estoy usando la herramienta de desarrollo **Laragon** corre en Windows 10.
después de configurar los diferentes Virtual host para el desarrollo, he intentado configurar la version que cada uno requiere, el cual me funciona correctamente siempre y cuando NO se ejecuten simultáneamente, ya que el cambio entre versiones de php requiere detener los servicios y hacer un switch manual.

```
vhost1.me == 5.6.1
vhost2.me == 7.2
vhost3.me == 7.4
vhost4.me == 8.2
```

ignorando la opción que se puede cambiar con un clic. Necesito ver el mismo desarrollo con dos versiones de php ejecutándose al mismo tiempo desde entonces; En 5.6.1 tengo una api y en 7.2 y 7.4 un desarrollo que la consume y estoy migrando estas dos últimas a 8.0

Anteriormente he realizado la configuración del archivo httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directorio "C:\laragon\my_old_project1">
<FilesMatch ".php$">
Aplicación SetHandler/x-httpd-php56-cgi
</FilesMatch>
</Directorio>

<Directorio "C:\laragon\my_old_project2">
<FilesMatch ".php$">
Aplicación SetHandler/x-httpd-php72-cgi
</FilesMatch>
</Directorio>

<Directorio "C:\laragon\my_old_project3">
<FilesMatch ".php$">
Aplicación SetHandler/x-httpd-php74-cgi
</FilesMatch>
</Directorio>

<Directorio "C:\laragon\my_old_project4">
<FilesMatch ".php$">
Aplicación SetHandler/x-httpd-php80-cgi
</FilesMatch>
</Directorio>
```

pero no puedo hacer que funcione ... principalmente esto que no lo puedo encontrar en `php.ini`:

```
SetEnv PHPRC "\ruta\a\xampp\php"
```

Entonces desconozco que otra configuración puedo agregar o me hace falta en el archivo de Virtual Host o php.ini?

**nota:**
no encontré nada relacionado a esta configuración dentro de la documentación del stack Laragon.
Asumo que si se utiliza apache o nginx, como parte del servicio web, debe tener un punto en comun de configuración.

La implementación a seguir esta semi-documentada en esta respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/4717133

Segun lo indica este punto: ***"Step 4 (option 3): [Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost]"***

Comment: si entiendo tu comentario y tu punto de vista pero no es lo que se busca con este post. si yo pregunto por alternativas como docker o vagrant; la pregunta estuviera basada en opiniones y seria fácilmente cerrada; muy amablemente te gradezco los datos pero, necesito comentarios y respuestas basado en la pregunta y no en sugerencias de implementar otras tecnologías que desconozco y que a lo mejor me tomaría mucho tiempo implementar correctamente; cuando ya estoy a un paso de terminar esta configuración.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya lo he resulto, de la siguiente forma:

Siguiendo este post del sitio en ingles para **XAMPP**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/4717133

Con algunos cambios para que funcione en **Laragon**.
Las versiones PHP NTS (non threat safe) NO son compatibles con Laragon.

**Paso 1:** Descarga PHP

Descargamos las versiones de PHP que vamos a utilizar, y las descomprimimos y las llevamos al directorio de php en Laragon: `C:\laragon\bin\php` en donde las ubicaremos, debemos colocarles un nombre amigable como: `\php70\` o `\php72\` o `\php74\` cual sea el escenario; **Muy importante** debemos verificar que cada version cuenta con el archivo `php-cgi.exe` ya que alguna versiones de php antiguas no lo incorporaron; y este es un requisito.

**Paso 2:** configurar `php.ini`

En cada version de php que usaremos debemos ir al archivo `C:\laragon\bin\php\php##\php.ini` (donde ## es la version de php) en un editor de código o texto. Si el archivo no existe, copie php.ini-development en php.ini y ábralo. Luego buscaremos y des-comentaremos la siguiente línea:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

y la modificaremos:

```
extension_dir =  "C:/laragon/bin/php/php72/ext"
```

con esto nos aseguraremos que php apuntara al directorio correcto de sus extensiones.

**Paso 3:** configurar apache

vamos directamente al directorio de configuración de apache: `C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\conf` (puede variar según la version de apache usada) y abrimos con un editor de código o texto el archivo `httpd.conf` por cada version de php que deseamos utilizar debemos crear un alias http y ejecutar el php-cgi correspondiente, esto debe colocarse al final del archivo:

```
# Ejemplo para php 7.2:

ScriptAlias /php72 "C:/laragon/bin/php/php72"
Action application/x-httpd-php72-cgi /php72/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/laragon/bin/php/php72">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

# Ejemplo para php 7.4:

ScriptAlias /php74 "C:/laragon/bin/php/php74"
Action application/x-httpd-php74-cgi /php74/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/laragon/bin/php/php74">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Nota: Puede agregar más versiones de PHP a su instalación de Paragón siguiendo los pasos 1 a 3 si lo desea.

**Paso 4:** configurar Virtual Host

Debemos ir al directorio: `C:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled` el cual es el lugar donde Laragon tiene los archivos de configuración de los Virtual Host; dependiendo de que proyectos tengamos debemos abrir cada archivo de configuración con un editor de código o texto:

*Original:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/prueba/"
    ServerName prueba.me
    ServerAlias *.prueba.me
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/prueba/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Modificado:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/prueba/"
    ServerName prueba.me
    ServerAlias *.prueba.me
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/prueba/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php72-cgi
        #SetHandler application/x-httpd-php74-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

donde el `SetHandler` definido hará referencia al Alias a utilizar.
y Finalizamos reiniciando los servicios web o el equipo.

No encuentre ni obtuve el error:

> Update for Error: malformed header from script 'php-cgi.exe': Bad
> header

no fue necesario definir, modificar o usar la variable de entorno de tiempo de ejecución:

```
SetEnv PHPRC "\\ruta\\a\\php\\"
```