Desplegegar xnova en xampp resulta no ser compatible: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
en el xampp 3.3.0 entoy tratando de montar el server del xnova y me sale este error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\GeneralFunctions.php:347 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\common.php(47): doquery('SELECT * FROM {...', 'config') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(25): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\GeneralFunctions.php on line 347


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Las funciones mysql_* están obsoletas y removidas de PHP hace años. Si necesitas si o si esas instrucciones, debes usar PHP 5.x. Puedes descargar la versión 5.6.40 de Xampp. Es posible que te salgan Warnings, pero puedes apagarlos desde php.ini o usar una versión más antigua de Xampp y que sea soportado por tu SO.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? ¿Por qué me sale el error "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()"?

Cuando mencionas XAMPP 3.3.0 ten en cuenta que esta es la versión de panel de control de xampp ... también ten en cuenta que esta versión puede incluir las versiones de PHP 7.4.33-0 / 8.0.25-0 / 8.1.12-0 y aquí es donde está el problema ya que el driver mysql fue removido en php 7.0
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
Por lo tanto es normal que obtengas el resultado en mencionas o error...
Ya que te indica que estas intentando implementar algo que no está en los recursos del servidor apache, esto puede pasar también con otras extensiones deprecadas y removidas o muy recientes que no estén aun en la versión de php que usas.
Segun el Contexto:
A. Si fuera un nuevo proyecto que estas iniciando te recomendaría que implementes estos otros drivers PDO y MySQLi.
B. Pero al ser la implementación de un proyecto existente ya documento como xnova server no puedo pretender que te pongas a cambiar código del proyecto… si no buscar cumplir con el requerimiento, para resolverlo tendrías que instalar una versión previa de php y/o compatible, aquí hay una guía:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432920/315134
Ten en cuenta, es posible que los hosting web en algún momento no ofrezcan soporte para versiones anterior a php 7.0 y no podrás subirlo a este hosting.

La solución más apropiada sería usar mysqli_connect o PDO en vez de mysql_connect. Cambiar la versión de PHP a una anterior puede traer más problemas a largo plazo, ya que puede ser o bien vulnerable o incompatible.

@Rodrigo creo que no entendiste el contexto ...  tu solucion seria agarar su la implementacion que tiene de xnova y pasarlo a mysqli o PDO ...  si fue un chiste fue malo ...

por favor no respondan preguntas que claramente son duplicados o que no estan bien formuladas.

@clay duplicado de que o que???

esta pregunta se ha hecho muchas veces en stackoverflow https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+mysql_connect%28%29

@clay estas equivocado:  el contexto lo cambia todo: entoy tratando de montar el server del xnova si bien el error es el mismo, no se puede resolver por el camino habitual ...

@clay lo unico que estan haciendo es bandalizar una buena pregunta ... que se sale del contexto habitual ...

Me parece la respuesta no está mal ya que el OP no está practicando, ni desarrollando en PHP, si no que quiere desplegar un sistema, que al parecer, es bastante antiguo y posiblemente no sepa nada del lenguaje. Curiosamente varios comentan, le dan negativo, pero ninguno vota por el cierre de la pregunta, incluso hay algunos con el privilegio suficiente para hacerlo de una vez.

@aeportugal por eso digo que es bandalismo... haca hay una publicacion en meta relacionada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5684/responder-el-contexto-o-responder-al-error
